# Avoiding Initial Memory Heap Size Error

Tags: java, memory-management

I run a Java code with the following command:

```
$ java -Xms4G -Xmx4G myjavacode
```

My cpu's RAM capacity is 6GB.

However it always fail to execute giving me this 
error message:

```
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms5G
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Could not create the Java virtual machine
```

Is there any way to set up Java option so that we can
execute the code?

Comment: Which JVM are you using?

Comment: @roland: jdk1.6.0_14/bin/java

Comment: Are you sure you're running the 64 bit JVM? That much memory can't be addressed in 32 bit.

Comment: @diciu: how can I check whether I use 32bit/64bit JVM? My linux machine is 64bit though.

Comment: There's usually a "-d64" arg to the JVM that instructs it to start in 64 bit if possible. Just run the JVM on the command line, it will list all of the possible args.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You've exceeded the maximum heap size of your JVM. This is both JVM and OS dependent. In most 32-bit systems the maximum value will be 2Gb, regardless of the physical memory available.

Comment: On windows 32-bit the limit is closer to 1.3 GB

Comment: I get the error `Invalid initial heap size: -Xms256m -Xmx512m` on a system with 16GB RAM (14GB free)

Answer (score 13):

By default Java will run in 32 bit mode.  Be sure to give it the -d64 option to put it into 64 bit mode.  Once in 64-bit mode, you shouldn't have any trouble allocating a 6GB JVM.

Comment: Do you mean that a 64 bit JVM also runs in 32 bit mode by default?

Comment: my issue got resolved with this -d64 parameter on Solaris Sparc 64bit with a Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b06) java. thanks

Comment: This makes no sense, but yes, it does seem to be the case on AWS `4.14.72-68.55.amzn1.x86_64` amazon linux as well, where 64-bit openjdk 1.8 is the default. Confusingly, the problem won't even go away if you just tack on d64 like `-Xms4g -Xmx16g -d64`. It will only work in this order: `-d64 -Xms4g -Xmx16g`

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the maximum memory size on 32-bit systems can vary, being anything up to 4 GB, but 2 GB is a common value. It's often possible to re-link your kernel to increase this to 3 or 3.5 GB. The issue, of course, is that you just don't have the address space to map more memory. Have you tried a 64-bit machine?

Also, remember to set your ulimit higher before you do this.