# Error when build apk, Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g

Tags: java, android

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:compileFlavorReleaseSources
:collectFlavorReleaseMultiDexComponents
:proguardFlavorRelease
Warning:can't write resource [.readme] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:.readme])
:shrinkFlavorReleaseMultiDexComponents
:createFlavorReleaseMainDexClassList
:retraceFlavorReleaseMainDexClassList
:dexFlavorRelease
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error:Execution failed for task ':dexFlavorRelease'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Any one can help me?

Comment: Hint --- `Invalid maximum heap size`. Another one --- `The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size`

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909018/avoiding-initial-memory-heap-size-error