# Starting Stanford CoreNLP server - Java heap size error

Tags: java, server, stanford-nlp

I am trying to start Stanford CoreNLP server the [link](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html#getting-started)

The following command:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 15000
```

generates error message:

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Just in case, here is my java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_31"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_31-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.31-b07, mixed mode)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4g" so it thinks that last part from the command thing is a heap size?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Just FYI, the same command worked on Ubuntu.

Comment: `java -mx4g` is a typo in the docs should be `java -Xmx4g`. Are you using a 32bit jvm when you get this error ?

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis.`java -Xmx4g` did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an issue with you running in 32-bit mode instead of 64-bit.

Try adding `-d64` to your command.

This thread goes into more detail about this kind of error:

[Avoiding Initial Memory Heap Size Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909018/avoiding-initial-memory-heap-size-error)