# Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS. Invalid max heap size?

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

So, I was trying to run my test Minecraft mod in Prompt as per a tutorial. In one part, I should type in 'gradlew getIntellijRuns' and everything should run smoothly. Instead, this message appears: -

*I've even tried "Xmx4096m", but it generates the same message.*

```
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx4G
The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Comment: I believe that your answer may be here (already answered): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/909018/avoiding-initial-memory-heap-size-error

Comment: @JulianMummery Well, I tried a few things. My Java HotSpot runs in a 64-bit environment. Unfortunately, I couldn't really find my answer there.

Comment: @TheL3rNa3aN I suspect you're running 32-bit Java on a 64-bit system. Replace it with 64-bit Java.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'll do that. We'll see how it goes.

Comment: If I'm gonna reinstall java, which one should I choose? Javax64 or Javax86?

Comment: x64 is 64-bit and x86 is 32-bit, so x64.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I solved the issue! So, I had allotted a bit too much RAM for _JAVA_OPTIONS. I tried '-Xmx1024m' and it worked brilliantly. And also, I made a small mistake in compiling the Gradle project via Command Prompt.

This is what I had typed: -
`gradlew getIntellijRuns`

And what I was supposed to type: -
`gradlew genIntellijRuns`

I found this out when I typed this: -
`gradlew tasks`

This command lists all available commands for the project. That way, I rectified my mistake.